# Weird behaivor when iterating over select element

Tags: jquery

Consider following snippet:

```
<html>    
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#test-selected").each(function () {
                var val = $(this).val();
                var text = $(this).text();
                alert(val);
                alert(text);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="test-selected">
        <option value="val1">text1</option>
        <option value="val2">text2</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

This looks pretty straightforward, but it becomes weird when running. Since there are only 2 `option` elements an iteration should run twice, right?

And it should `alert` on first iteration

```
val1
text1
```

On a second

```
val2
text2
```

This is what expected.

But instead, iteration runs only once, on first it alerts `val1` on second it alerts `text1, text2`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop the `option` instead of `select` element:

```
$("#test-selected option").each(function(){
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GUm58/)**

Comment: Okay, but why? Looks like `$.each()` contain all children (which are `options` in this case)?

Comment: No, the children are not included here. `.each()` is only iterate over the matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

use [**$.each()**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$("#test-selected option").each(function(){
//your code here
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xDrHK/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test-selected").filter("option").each(function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

**$("#test-selected")** is selecting only **Select** field and it is only one if you want to iterate the options then use

```
$("#test-selected option")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're iterating over all the `select` box in DOM. since `id` belongs to only one `select` box it returns the selected value and options in it. You need to iterate over the `options` to get your expected result.

Try this instead.

```
 $("#test-selected option").each(function(){

            var val = $(this).val();
            var text = $(this).text();

            alert(val); 
            alert(text);

        });
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUdj7/)